# Atualizar aplicação a cada 5 segundos

Tags: android

Boa noite.

Preciso fazer uma aplicação que faça uma requisição http a cada 5 segundos e traga o resultado da mesma que é em formato Json.

Bom, essa parte da requisição e obtenção dos dados eu já implementei usando Retrofit e Gson.

Agora preciso saber o que usar para fazer essa solicitação a cada 5 segundos e como manter a aplicação fazendo essas requisições mesmo depois de sair do aplicativo ou encerrá-lo.

Eu implementei o Service e ficou assim:

```
public class MyService extends Service {

private static final String TAG = "pendentesErro";
private static final String TAG_SUCESSO = "pendentes";

String fila = "";
int total = 0;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(timerTask, 2000, 5000);
}

private Timer timer;
private TimerTask timerTask = new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        total = 0;

        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(FilaPendentesService.URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();

        FilaPendentesService service = retrofit.create(FilaPendentesService.class);
        Call<FilaPendentes> requestPendentes = service.ListPendentes();

        requestPendentes.enqueue(new Callback<FilaPendentes>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<FilaPendentes> call, Response<FilaPendentes> response) {
                if (!response.isSuccessful()) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "ERRO: " + response.code());
                } else {
                    FilaPendentes filaPendentes = response.body();

                    for (Pendente p : filaPendentes.Pendentes) {

                        String operadora = String.format("%s: ", p.Operadora);
                        String quantidade = String.format("%s ", p.Quantidade);

                        total = total + Integer.parseInt(p.Quantidade);

                        fila = (operadora + quantidade + "\n\n");

                        Log.i(TAG_SUCESSO, fila + "\n\n");
                    }
                    Log.i(TAG_SUCESSO, "Total: " + String.valueOf(total));
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<FilaPendentes> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Erro: " + t.getMessage());
            }
        });
    }
};

@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}
```

}

Agora queria saber como recuperar esses valores que estou mostrando no log em uma Activity.

Comment: Espero que essas requisições de 5 em 5 segundos não durem muito tempo, porque acabam com a bateria. Mesmo de 1 em 1 minuto já acaba. Se precisa monitorar o estado de um servidor, o melhor é usar *push notifications*.

Comment: Tem alguns links?

Comment: Firebase Cloud Messaging, antigo GCM: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/
Entendendo o consumo de bateria: https://developer.android.com/training/efficient-downloads/efficient-network-access.html?hl=pt-br

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sugiro **não** usar threads para agendar a requisição periódica, depois de ter tratado a requisição anterior. Algo no estilo:

```
final int delay = 5000;
final int period = 5000;
final Runnable r = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        ... executa a requisição ...
        postDelayed(this, period);
    }
};

postDelayed(r, delay);
```

Você deve implementar essa parte do aplicativo como um Service, que pode rodar independente da Activity (parte visível). Assim a Activity pode ser fechada e o Service continua rodando. Você pode até implementar inicialmente na Activity para fazer funcionar e testar, mas em seguida deve encapsular num Service.

Os guidelines do Android determinam que um Service que fique rodando em background deve mostrar uma notificação "grudenta" ou "sticky" (que não pode ser removida), para que o usuário saiba que existe o Service (de forma análoga a um reprodutor de música que mantém um item preso na lista de notificações).

Para um serviço ter grande chance de ficar na memória, inicie-o a partir da Activity usando o método startForeground e passando uma notificação "sticky" como parâmetro (documentação: [https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#startForeground(int, android.app.Notification)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#startForeground(int,%20android.app.Notification)) )

Ainda assim, o **Android tem toda a liberdade** de matar um Service que rode em background. Mesmo com a sticky notification. que diminui mas não elimina a chance de morte. Salvo melhor juízo não existe forma de garantir que um Service dure para sempre.

Para compensar este risco, supondo que você realmente precisa que o serviço seja executado o tempo todo, a solução é cadastrar um Alarme, via AlarmManager (documentação https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html).

O alarme só vai durar enquanto o celular estiver rodando, mas isso é facilmente consertado criando um "receiver" para o evento android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED, que será executado quando o celular reiniciar. Lá você volta a cadastrar o mesmo alarme. Segue um esqueleto de como fazer essa ligação entre evento e código: http://www.learn-android-easily.com/2013/07/bootcompleted-broadcastreceiver-in.html